# Counting problem: possible sudoko tables?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a sudoko solver (python). my method is using a game tree and explore possible permutations for each set of digits by DFS Algorithm.

in order to analyzing problem, i want to know what is the count of possible **valid and invalid** sudoko tables?

-> a 9*9 table that have 9 one, 9 two, ... , 9 nine.

(this isn't exact duplicate by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512598/maths-question-number-of-different-permutations))

my solution is:

1- First select 9 cells for 1s: (*)
[image]
<sub>(source: [sitmo.com](https://www.sitmo.com/gg/latex/latex2png.2.php?z=100&eq=%5Cmathbf%7BC%7D(9%2C81)%3D%5Cfrac%7B81!%7D%7B(81-9)!%5Ctimes9!%7D))</sub>

2- and like (1) for other digits (each time, 9 cells will be deleted from remaining available cells):
C(81-9,9) , C(81-9*2,9) .... =
[image]
<sub>(source: [sitmo.com](https://www.sitmo.com/gg/latex/latex2png.2.php?z=100&eq=%5Cprod_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B9%7D%20%7B%5Cmathbf%7BC%7D(9%2C81-9(i-1))%7D%3D%20%5Cprod_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B9%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B(81-9(i-1))!%7D%7B(81-9%20%20i)!%5Ctimes%209!%7D%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B81!%7D%7B9!%5E9%7D))</sub>

3- finally multiply the result by 9! (permutation of 1s-2s-3s...-9s in (*))
[image]
<sub>(source: [sitmo.com](https://www.sitmo.com/gg/latex/latex2png.2.php?z=100&eq=%5Cfrac%7B81!%7D%7B9!%5E9%7D%5Ctimes%209!%3D%5Cfrac%7B81!%7D%7B9!%5E8%7D))</sub>

this is not equal to accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512598/maths-question-number-of-different-permutations) but problems are equivalent. what did i do wrong?

Comment: Try MathOverflow, this isn't a programming issue at this stage.

Comment: @ Lazarus: i think it's related to, because it's appeared when try to solve a programming problem.

Comment: @Lazarus: per its FAQ, MathOverflow is for "research level math questions".

Comment: @Sorush, then it should be expressed as a programming problem rather than a math problem. You haven't shown a single line of code but lots of forumlae. Describing an analytical process and asking for help on it wouldn't make it a programming problem just because you are writing a program to solve that problem, the issue is with the theory not the practice. It's a very simple distinction.

Comment: @AakashM, oh... so just because it doesn't fit MathOverflow's FAQ definition, it must fit on StackOverflow even though it doesn't fit SO's FAQ. Jeez.

Comment: @Lazarus: I didn't say it was a good fit for SO. I made no comment on that issue, in fact. My intent was to point out that suggesting MO for this question would be inappropriate.

Comment: @AakashM, but by inference, you have only chided me for suggesting it should go to MathOverflow rather than Sorush for posting here and you haven't voted for the question to be closed, there is a pretty good indication that you support this question being here. At least be clear and state the fact that you feel I was wrong in indicating that this question shouldn't be on SO. It's a boolean at the end of the day, True/False, Yes/No, SO/Not SO. Ambiguity drives bad behaviour. Man, I feel better for that rant :)

Comment: @Lazarus: boolean? not so! our Illustrious Leader has blogged on that very subject: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/  . In fact I said only 'not MO' because that is all I am *sure* of: my own opinions about what does/n't belong on __S__ O have been at odds with 'the community' enough that I lean towards inaction on *that* issue...

Comment: @AakashM, oh well. It got answered regardless... another nail in SO's coffin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of valid Sudoku solution grids for the standard 9×9 grid was calculated by Bertram Felgenhauer and Frazer Jarvis in 2005 to be 6,670,903,752,021,072,936,960.

[Mathematics of Sudoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#cite_note-afj2-2) | 
[source](http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/sudoku/)

I think problem with your solution is that deleting 9 cells each time from available cells does not necessarily create a valid grid. What I mean is just deleting 9 cells won't suffice.

That is why 81! / (9!)^9 is much bigger number than actual valid solutions.

**EDIT:**

[Permutations with repeated elements](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/cs310-04w/notes/dm-morecomb.pdf)

Your solutions is almost correct if you want all the tables not just valid sudoku tables.

There is a formula:

(a+b+c+...)! / [a! b! c! ....]

Suppose there are 5 boys and 3 girls and we have 8 seats then number of different ways in which they can seat is

(5+3)! / (5! 3!)

Your problem is analogous to this one.

There are 9 1s , 9 2s ... 9 9s.
and 81 places

so answer should be (9+9+...)! / (9!)^9

Now if you multiply again by 9! then this will add duplicate arrangements to the number by shuffling them.

Comment: @TheMachineCharmer: i don't want number of valid tables. do you think count of valid n*n sudoko tables filled by digits of n+1 radix is NP Hard? the solution you referred, solves problem by counting. (like 4-color) :-)

Comment: Your solution seems correct if you want all the tables not just valid ones :)

Comment: @ TheMachineCharmer : Hm... so is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512598/maths-question-number-of-different-permutations an incorrect answer?

Comment: No your answer should be 81!/(9!)^9 actually. I ll explain in a moment ;)

Comment: I can't see why are you multiplying by 9! ? could you explain please? It is not necessary.

Comment: I select 9 cells for 1s. then 9 other cells for 2s & ... finally in each state i'll have 9 set of cells that in each one is just one digit. this 9 sets and 9 digits of them could be associated in 9! modes.

Comment: I don't think counting number of valid n*n sudoku tables filed by digits of n+1 radix is NP Hard. Because we have analytical method of calculating number of valid tables without actually counting them one by one. See the links.

Comment: No! :) you have already accounted for that possibility of 9! modes while choosing 9 cell for each digit. Shuffling any more will only produce duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku) (or [this OEIS sequence](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A107739)), there are roughly 6.6 * 10^21 different sudoku squares.

Answer (score 1):

What you did wrong was the last step: you shouldn't multiply the answer by `9!`. You have already counted all possible squares.

This doesn't help you much when counting the possible Sudoku-tables. One other thing you could do is to count the tables where the "row-condition" holds: that is just `(9!)^9`, because you just choose one permutation of `1..9` for every row.

Still closer to the Sudoku-problem is counting [Latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_squares). Latin square has to satisfy both the "row-condition" and "column condition". That is already a difficult problem and no closed form formula is known. Sudoku is a Latin square with the additional "subsquare-condition".